# What is the possibilities of using RS232 Port in a satellite decoder to connect the internet

Tags: networking, conversion, internet-connection, connection-sharing

Can I use the RS232 port in my satellite decoder to connect and get internet access to my pc?

Comment: That largely depends on whether the satellite decoder has software or is set up to provide or get access to the internet via that port. RS232 has no defined protocols that it must support so it is up to the software on the device.

Answer (score 1):

No. The RS232 port is not meant to pass data to a connected device. These ports are used to do configuration, recovery or discovery functions on the satellite decoder itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, on so many levels. For starters, the baud rate of RS232 is way too low to get any meaningful connection.

Comment: The serial port could be used with modems (both analog and ISDN), so it is definitely fast enough.

Comment: OP doesn't mention use of a modem.

Comment: Used to use a 56K modem to connect to the Internet via RS232, so this *can* be done. I just don't know if we even still have ISPs that have banks of phone line modems any more. Granted this would be slow and painful in an era where even the most basic page is a couple of meg in html, css and scripts and would take at least a few minutes to just show a front page.

Comment: If OP doesn't mention use of a modem, they can get _higher_ speed than if they did! Analog modems were only limited to 30-50 kbps due to the _telephone_ link (and that's still enough for quite a few Internet services), whereas the RS232 serial link can definitely reach at least 1 Mbps.

Comment: @user1686 while it might be possible for an RS232 link to reach 1 megabit, this would not be common. The standard when these were popular was 115400bps or less. The fastest speed I saw was a bit under 1Mbps,